# What is wrong with the derivation for x coordinate of Centroid of quarter of a circle below?

Tags: civil-engineering, applied-mechanics

In the derivation for x coordinate of centroid of a quarter circle as shown in the image below why is the sign coming out to be negative when actually it should be positive?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the numerator of the very first expression of the equation for $\bar{X}$ is wrong. It should be,
$$\bar{X}=\dfrac{\displaystyle{\int_0^R xy\, dx}}{\displaystyle{\int dA}}.\tag{1}$$

Then, your integral becomes,
$$\bar{X}=-\dfrac{4R}{\pi}\displaystyle{\int}_{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}^0\cos\left(\theta\right)\sin^2\left(\theta\right)\,d\theta.\tag{2}$$

When you finish integrating this, you will get the positive value $\dfrac{4R}{3\pi}$ for $\bar{X}$.

Comment: But how come have you taken lower limit as pi/2 when theta clearly starts from zero? Shouldn't zero then be the lower limit and pi/2 the upper limit?

Comment: You should have a long look at your diagram. First, the integral in the numerator of (1) shows that $\pmb{x}$ goes from $\pmb{0}$ to $\pmb{R}$. Now, when $x=0$, we have $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and when $x=R$, $\theta$ is equal to 0. That is why the ntegral (2) goes from $\pmb{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$ to $\pmb{0}$.

Comment: Already had got it. Still nice to reply.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of the center of mass for a region bounded by the graph of a positive function $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is

$$\bar x = \frac{\int_{A} x dx d y }{\int_A dx d y } = \frac{\int_a^b x f(x) dx}{\int_a^b f(x) dx} \\
\bar y = \frac{\int_{A} y dx d y }{\int_A dx d y} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\int_a^b  f^2(x) dx}{\int_a^b f(x) dx} $$

In our case we get

$$\bar x = \frac{\int_0^R  x \sqrt{R^2- x^2} dx}{ \int_0^R   \sqrt{R^2- x^2} dx} \\
\bar y =\frac{\int_0^R (R^2 - x^2) d x}{ \int_0^R   \sqrt{R^2- x^2} dx} $$

so $\bar x = \bar y = \frac{4 R}{3 \pi}= 0.4244\ldots R$.

Notice that $\bar x = \bar y$, since the quarter circle has axis of symmetry the line $x = y$. The distance from the origin to the center of mass is $\frac{4 \sqrt{2} R}{3 \pi} = 0.600\ldots R$.

In general, for a homogenous circular sector of angle $\theta$ the center of mass is on the axis of symmetry at a distance from center $r_{\theta} = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \operatorname{sinc} \frac{\theta}{2} \cdot R$, so always under $\frac{2}{3}R$